# Paste in CKEditor on IE issues

Tags: internet-explorer, drupal, ckeditor

I am using CKEditor 4.5.3 on my Drupal site. When I try to paste any content into a page through the CKEditor in IE it wont allow it. And it's only in IE. Can anyone tell me why? Please help! Thank you in advance.

Comment: What have you done to debug? Are there JavaScript errors of some sort in your console? What version of IE?

Comment: CKEditor are loaded in iframes and IE may be blocking editor javascript to execute, try to minimize security level of IE and then check it.

Comment: @ceejayoz I have been looking online to see if there is anything I was missing when setting up the CKEditor in drupal or if anyone else was running into the same problem I was but I have had no luck. There is also no JavaScript errors in my console. I am currently running version 11 of IE. The paste just has no effect. There is nothing pasting in the CKEditor.

Comment: @ViswanathPolaki thank you for your input, but unfortunately I tried it and it didn't work. Also, since other people other than myself will be inputting content into the site using the CKEditor I want it to work and not have them take any extra steps in order for it to function. I appreciate your answer though. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

For Drupal 7 install the [WYSISYG](https://www.drupal.org/project/wysiwyg) module and then add CKEditor as a library in the libraries folder (e.g. sites/all/libraries/). The 7.x-2.2 version of WYSIWYG only supports CKEditor up to version 3.6.6.2. Be sure to download the correct version of the CKEditor library.